# An error occurred while calling the java function from jni

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I want to access the java function(transceive) from JNI. I get message error unfortunately, app has stopped when call transceive function from IsoDep.java

How to call transceive function when parameters and output in the form of an bytes array?

Please help me, thanks.

JMain.java

```
Class JMain {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("Native");
    }

    public native byte[] ReadData();
}
```

IsoDep.java

```
public byte[] transceive(byte[] data) throws IOException {
    //
}
```

Native.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEnv *JNI_GetEnv() {
   //
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *jvm, void *reserved) {
     //
}


jbyteArray SendReq(jobject isoDep, jbyteArray b) {
    // PROBLEM IN HERE..
    //   Error unfortunately, app has stopped when call transceive function
    //   from IsoDep.java
    jbyte *args = e->GetByteArrayElements(b, NULL); 
    return (jbyteArray) e->CallObjectMethodA(isoDep, _midTransceive, (jvalue *) args);  
}

JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL
Java_com_company_appname_JMain_ReadData(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    //
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

Comment: Edit and add the stack trace of the error.

Comment: Aside question: why would you call some `JNI_GetEnv()` method, when you get an `env` as a parameter?

Comment: @user2543253, Given a cached JavaVM interface pointer it is trivial to implement a utility function that allows the native code to obtain the JNIEnv interface pointer for the current thread.

Comment: @Erwin that might be the case, but you already have an JNIEnv interface pointer (i.e. had one in the original version of your question). No need to obtain an new one. Just because you can doesn't mean you need to.

Comment: @user2543253, you are right, thanks for point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `transceive` method wants a Java byte array reference (`jbyteArray`/`jobject`) as a parameter, not a C++ jbyte pointer (`jbyte*`).

When you extraxt the byte array's contents with `GetByteArrayElements` you get something that is only usable in the native code and not a valid Java reference (and passing that non-reference to a Java method is what makes your program crash). Omit that step and pass `b` directly.

Comment: This code resolved my problem return (jbyteArray)  e->CallObjectMethod(isoDep, _midTransceive, (jvalue *) b);